# Выполняется много запросов если успеть нажать много раз

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, post

Пишу приложение на ASP.NET и вопрос. Если при сохранении записи успеть нажать несколько раз, то создается несколько одинаковых записей. Как избавиться от этого? Ниже скрин того что происходит и кусок кода отвечающий за запрос.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Create(AdmissionViewModel model) //обработка добавления прихода исходя из данных в полях
{

    model.Balance = model.QuantityUp - model.QuantityDown;
    var type = await Repository.Types.FindAsync(model.Type.Id);
    var upload = await Repository.Uploads.FindAsync(model.Upload.Id);
    var kind = await Repository.Kinds.FindAsync(1);

    if (model.Type.Id > 5)//ОПРЕДЕЛЕНИЕ РАСХОДНИКОВ И ОБОРУДОВАНИЕ. ТОЧНЕЕ АВТОПОДСТАВЛЕНИЕ
    {
        kind = await Repository.Kinds.FindAsync(2);
    }

    Admission entity = new Admission(model.DateAdmission, type, model.Name, model.QuantityUp, model.QuantityDown, upload, DateTime.Now, kind);
    Repository.Admissions.Add(entity);

    await Repository.SaveChangesAsync();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: как вариант можно заморозить кнопку добавления при помощи JS

Comment: обычно так и делают, при нажатии на кнопку блокируют кнопку или весь экран до получения результата операции.

Answer (score 2):

Вам необходимо после нажатия кнопки блокировать её, посылать ajax запрос и разблокировать её после получения результата.